# Как вынести изображение в header за пределы container?

Tags: html, css

Есть дизайн, и в дизайне есть container фиксированной ширины и в нем есть картинка, которая выходит за пределы контейнера. Опробовал разные способы, в том числе обернув его в отдельный div, но ничего не помогло. Скажите пожалуйста, как можно вынести картинку за пределы контейнера?[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не видно на скрине что бы картинка была за контейнером

Comment: Что-то на ваших скриншотах ничего не разобрать. Упростите макет, нарисуйте желаемый результат, покажите фактический результат и код к нему, и где по-вашему происходит выход за пределы контейнера, потому что я на этих скриншотах тоже не вижу выхода за пределы контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Оберни картинку в div и задай этому div   margin 0 calc(-50vw + 50%)